# Access elements of an Observable Array

Tags: reactjs, mobx

[image]

I have a prop named blockers that returns an observable array of objects. These objects contain 'userId.'

How can I go about returning an array that contains these userIds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Computed observables](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) can help with situations like these. Make sure that your component is decorated as a `mobx-react` [@observer](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html), that way it will automatically make props observable.

```
@computed get userIds () {
  return this.props.blockers.map(blocker => blocker.userId)
}
```

Comment: Yup, just noticed that as well. Thanks for the help